# Two sites connected with wireless point to point: how to configure and ensure internet traffic goes through local broadband?

Tags: networking, remote

Scenario:

Two offices a short distance apart. Let's call them Main and Remote. Both have ADSL broadband. Windows network in Main. Currently different subnets. 192.168.16.x in Main and 192.168.0.x in Remote, masks 255.255.255.0

We are proposing to use a wireless point-to-point connection to allow Remote users to connect to the Main network. How can we configure this? Presumably we need to use different subnets otherwise all internet traffic will go through the ADSL in Main. We want seamless access to the Main network from Remote but for local and internet traffic to stay in Remote.

There is a managed switch in Remote but it is not doing anything smart currently.

Answer (score 5):

You need a router in both of your locations. Set the default route on both of them to the local broadband gateway. On the remote router set a route to 192.168.16.0 using the wireless link and in your main router a route to 192.168.0.0 using wireless.